# Is there a list of all of the cases in the Talmud where תיקו ("Teiku") is said?

Tags: words, talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, teiku

Sometimes in the gemara there are questions that for whatever reason are unable to be answered, and to such a question the gemara simply says "teiku" (usually translated to mean "let it stand").

**Does a list exists that gathered together all of the cases in the Talmud  where Teiku is invoked?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rabbi Aaron Pessin has an entire sefer dedicated to all the "teiku"s that appear in Shas. The entire Sefer can be found online [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=62143&width=0&scroll=0&udid=0&pagenum=1).

R' Pessin lists 317 times in Shas Bavli from Brachos 8a to Nidda 63a. There is a complete listing which is too large to copy here, but I can at least copy the breakdown by Mesechta.
 [image]