# List of all the times the Talmudic principle of "chiddush" is used in Shas

Tags: talmud-gemara, chiddush-talmudic-principle

<sub>(similar type of question asked about: "*[svara](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106367/list-of-all-the-times-the-principle-of-svara-is-used-in-shas)*", "[תיקו](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105231/is-there-a-list-of-all-of-the-cases-in-the-talmud-where-%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95-teiku-is-said)" "[Halachot L'Moshe MiSinai](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/list-of-halachot-limosheh-misinai)")</sub>

The Talmudic principle of "*chiddush*" is sometimes invoked to explain certain areas of halacha. Namely, there are some rules and foundations that **do not** follow the usual halakhic rules, **and thus their *own* rules cannot be extrapolated from or to other areas of halacha**.

A couple examples of this principle of *chiddush* are:

- "[*Eidim Zomemim*](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.27a.3?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Sanhedrin.27a.3.1&lang2=bi)"- conspiring witnesses (**chiddush**: we believe the second set of witnesses instead of the first)
- "[*Motzi Shem Ra*](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Intercourse.3.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi)"- a person who claims his wife committed adultery (**chiddush**: if wife is guilty she is executed by stoning instead of strangulation)

Is there a comprehensive list of all the places in Shas where the Talmudic principle of *chiddush* is used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The (Hebrew) [Wikipedia entry on "***chiddush***"](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9#%D7%98%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%9C_%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%A9) has a chart that lists **20** such instances in Shas where the principle of "*chiddush*"is invoked.

**NOTE**: for English translation of this list, please see below said image

[image]

1) **חיוב קרבן בשבועת ביטוי** - an “oath of expression” about a future or past event (ie NOT an oath of testimony)

- **chiddush**- a negative commandment that isn't punishable by *kareis* requires a korban (see [Shevuot 26b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shevuot.26b.3-5?lang=bi&with=Tosafot&lang2=en) with Tosfos)

2) **בשר בחלב**  - meat and milk

- **chiddush**-
  a) 2 individually permitted things together are forbidden
  b)the prohibition is ***just*** in the cooking of them together- ie if one were to soak meat in milk it would be fine (see [Pesachim 44b](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.44b.8-11?lang=bi))

3) **גיעולי עובדי כוכבים** - purging the vessels of non-Jews with boiling water

- **chiddush**- usually a utensil which imparts a bad flavor to food is permitted. However by vessels of non-Jews, *even* if the vessels impart a bad flavor the food is still prohibited
  (see [Pesachim 44b](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.44b.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

4) **קנס** - paying a penalty

- **chiddush**- Paying despite being killed (see [Ketubot 38b](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.38b.6-7?lang=bi))

5) **נזיר** - an instance of accepting a nazirite vow upon oneself

- **chiddush**- if a person says he's a nazir from grape seeds (ie accepting a partial nazirite vow upon himself) he's a full nazir (see [Nazir 3b-4a](https://www.sefaria.org/Nazir.3b.10-4a.3?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en))

6) **שפחה כנענית לעבד עברי** - Canaanite maidservant to a Jewish slave

- **chiddush**- a Jewish male is permitted to marry a non-Jewish woman  (see [Kiddushin 21b](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.21b.13?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Kiddushin.21b.13.1&lang2=bi) with Rashi)

7) **אשת יפת תואר** - a beautiful woman who was taken captive in war

- **chiddush**- a non-Jewish woman is permitted to a Jew (inferred from [Kiddushin 21b](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.21b.17-21?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en))

8) **עדים זוממים**  - conspiring witnesses

- **chiddush**- we rely on the 2nd set of witnesses (see [Sanhedrin 27a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.27a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

9) **ריבית** - charging interest

- **chiddush**- the borrower who loses money *also* violates a prohibition (see [Bava Metzia 61a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.61a.7-14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

10) **טומאת שרץ** - if a *sheretz* (creepy crawly creature) imparts "flavor" to a mixture it is *still* prohibited

- **chiddush**- even though it's gross & imparts flavor to the detriment of the mixture (and should thus be permitted) it's *still* forbidden. (see [Avodah Zarah 68b](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.68b.11-12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

11) **טומאת שכבת זרע** - impurity of an emission that's imparted into a mixture is *still* prohibited

- **chiddush**- see above ([Avodah Zarah 68b](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.68b.14-15?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en))

12) **זרוע של איל נזיר** - the foreleg of the ram offering that a nazirite must bring

- **chiddush**- it's permitted to nullify a prohibited item *even* from the outset (*lchatchilah*)
  (see [Chullin 98b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.98b.9?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Chullin.98b.9.1&lang2=bi))

13) **חלב בהמה טהורה** - permissibility of consuming milk from a kosher animal

- **chiddush** - milk originates from the blood (akin to *ever min hachai*) and yet the Torah still permits it (see [Bechoros 6a-b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bekhorot.6a.1-6b.24?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

14) **צרעת הבתים** - leprosy on houses

- **chiddush**- rocks and trees can be *mekabel tumah* (see [Moed Kattan 7b-8a](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.7b.13-8a.1?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en))

15) **יבמה** - the widow of a childless man who has brothers

- **chiddush**- an *ervah* (ie brother's wife) is permitted (see [Yevamos 17b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.17b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

16) **נבלת עוף טהור** - the carcass of a pure bird

- **chiddush**- rather than by touching or carrying, one contracts *tumah* by eating the carcass of a pure-- ie kosher-- bird (see [Zevachim 70a](https://www.sefaria.org/Zevachim.70a.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

17) **מנחת העומר** - the Omer offering

- **chiddush**- a korban of barley is brought (inferred from [Menachos 5a-b](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.5a.1-5b.25?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en))

18) **טומאת בעלי קרי בהר סיני** - the impurity of a person who had an emission by Har Sinai

- **chiddush**- in this instance the Torah is more stringent with a *baal keri* than with a *zav* or a *metzora* (see [Niddah 42a](https://www.sefaria.org/Niddah.42a.11-12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

19) **מזיד בשבועת ביטוי** - purposely taking a *shevuas bitui*

- **chiddush**- a person purposely taking a *shevuas bitui* (ie “oath of expression”- NOT an oath of testimony) is obligated to bring a korban (see [Shevuot 37a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shevuot.37a.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

20) **מוציא שם רע** -  a man who claims his wife committed adultery

- **chiddush**- if the woman is guilty of the *motzi shem ra* claim against her she is executed by stoning- despite the fact that if she were to commit the sin in her current state (ie as a regular married woman without a *motzi shem ra* claim) she would be executed via strangulation
  (see [Ketubot 45a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.45a.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

Comment: It appears that there's always an ikkar chiddush. For example: by Eidim Zomemeim the chiddush is that we believe the 2nd set. Once we have this "anchor" chiddush in place, Rava & Abaye can have their 2nd machlokes of lmafrea who nifsal vs mkaan u'lehaba hu nifsal... again, all anchored in the fact that we believe the 2nd set.